# Why can't the $rootScope be accessed in the html call to the directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, angularjs-scope, ng-grid

I'm using ng-csv to allow users to download a csv of their data. The code  that creates the download link is appended to the page HTML from a common plugins module. In the common module, I set the export data to a rootScope variable so that it can be called from the view, except it is just return a blank document. Where am I off?

Relevant plugins code:

```
function getOutput(){
    return csvStringify(csvOutput);
}
var stringifiedOutput = csvStringify(csvOutput);

csvDataLinkHtml += "<span type='button' lazy-load='true' ng-csv='$root.csvOutput' csv-header='"+csvStringify(headers)+"' filename='data.csv' class='csv-data-link-span'><i class='fa fa-file-excel-o excel-icon'></i></span>";

$(function() {
  angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    var link = $compile(csvDataLinkHtml);
    csvDataLinkHtml = link(scope);
    fp.append(csvDataLinkHtml);
    $rootScope.csvOutput = stringifiedOutput;
  });
});
```

To clarify, this is an ng-grid plugin.

Comment: Where's `getOutput`? In a controller? Why are you accessing `this.csvOutput` instead of `$scope.csvOutput` or `$rootScope.csvOutput`?

Comment: getOutput is another function in the plugins file. the code i pasted above is in a common plugins file referenced by many pages with different data that will become csvOutput, not in a controller, and so I couldn't set/get $scope.csvOutput.

Comment: So if you are not inside a controller why are you trying to access stuff on `$rootScope`? `$rootScope` is not a reference to `document`. `$rootScope` is a service you inject as a dependency to other AngularJS "things" like controllers and other services.

Comment: In the plugin code, I want to set a scope variable equal to stringifiedOutput that can then be referenced in the HTML: `"<span type='button' lazy-load='true' ng-csv='$root.csvOutput' csv-header='"+csvStringify(headers)+"' filename='data.csv' class='csv-data-link-span'><i class='fa fa-file-excel-o excel-icon'></i></span>";` I thought using a rootScope var might work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Got it. First of all stop building HTML like that. That's one of the reasons you use AngularJS. Second look into AngularJS services. Those are a better way of sharing resources between controllers/directives. Also make sure you understand that `$scope` and `$rootScope` don't exist outside an AngularJS context.

Comment: How would you better format the HTML? I've considered setting the var in services but would prefer a simpler solution as I have about 40 controllers that would need to set the scope variable.

Comment: I'm talking about `csv-header='"+csvStringify(headers)+"'`. Why are you doing that? Is `csvStringify` a global function? Don't do that. Use services. There's nothing complicated in doing so and besides a common parent `$scope` there's no other _clean_ and _reliable_ way of sharing scope between controllers.

Comment: Perhaps you missed my last comment, but once again, I've considered setting the var in services but would prefer a simpler solution as I have about 40 controllers that would need to set the scope variable. I received your suggestion to use services loud and clear.

Comment: But you did not respond to me saying that there's no such thing as `$rootScope` outside of AngularJS code where it's injected. So again, `$rootScope.csvOutput = 'foo'` is not the same as `window.csvOutput = 'foo'`. In the first case you need to get a reference to `$rootScope` and only the Dependency Injector (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) can do that. `var stringifiedOutput = csvStringify(csvOutput);` cannot possibly work if you set `$rootScope.csvOutput`. It would work if you set  `window.csvOutput`.

Comment: Thanks Sergiu, that's what I was looking for. We ended up using window.csvOutput. Not the most elegant solution, but works for our needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing some context from the code example, but you're probably linking the template with a different scope.

Try selecting your desired element in chrome inspector and type `angular.element($0).scope()` in the console to grab the associated scope. 
I'm guessing you probably want to do a `$rootScope.$new()` and link that with the new element.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up setting the csv data to window.csvData, and changing a few lines of code in the ng-csv directive:

```
function getOutput(){
    return csvStringify(csvOutput);
}
var stringifiedOutput = csvStringify(csvOutput);


window.csvMyData = csvOutput;
var csvDataLinkHtml = "<div class='ngHeaderButton2'><span type='button' lazy-load='true' ng-csv='[]' ng-csv-reference='csvMyData' csv-header='"+csvStringify(headers)+"' filename='data.csv' class='csv-data-link-span'><i class='fa fa-file-excel-o excel-icon'></i></span></div>";

$(function() {
  angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
    var link = $compile(csvDataLinkHtml);
    csvDataLinkHtml = link(scope);
    fp.append(csvDataLinkHtml);
  });
});
```